# Evernote hijacked my CTRL+Alt+V shortcut. How can I get it back?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, evernote

I use CTRL+Alt+V to "paste special" all the time. Unfortunately, Evernote has hijacked the functionality, so my shortcut key creates a new note instead of doing what I want.

How can I disable the Evernote shortcut?

Comment: +1 just for letting me know that Ctrl-Alt-V invokes paste special. That will save me time every day.

Comment: Until I stumbled on this post, I was mistakenly under the impression that office 2010 had removed the ctrl-alt-v shortcut.  I had not yet put together the use of ctrl-alt-v with these weird fragments of word documents appearing in evernote...thanks.

Comment: Is there a Mac version of this question?  The new version of Evernote (Oct 2020) has recently introduced global hotkeys that are superseding hotkeys in other programs with no obvious way to disable.

Comment: See my comment below. Keyboard shortcuts are now editable in Help -> Keyboard shortcuts, or by pressing Ctrl + /

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of two ways:

1. In Evernote, from the Menu bar Choose Tools then Options then the "Hot Keys" tab, and reassign the operation using Ctrl+Alt+V (typically Paste Clipboard).
2. Right click the Evernote Clipper icon in your system tray, Options, and "Configure Hotkeys", and the same reassignment done above.

Comment: See @user366114's answer for more recent versions of Evernote.

Answer (score 5):

Evernote version 5.5.1 is different. There is no "tools" tab on the menubar and you instead must go to Evernote> preferences> shortcuts.

Comment: As of 6.5.4, in the Windows Application it is Tools > Options > Shortcut Keys

It is still Options > Configure Shortcut Keys ... in the Evernote Clipper in the system tray.

Thanks for prompting an update to the question!

Comment: As of 10.4.4, Evernote from the Microsoft Store does not appear to have a way to configure *any* keyboard shortcuts: all I see is Tools > Account Info and Tools > Preferences > Save data at log out.

Answer (score 1):

In Evernote 10.8.x and newer, they have moved this menu. Local and global keyboard shortcuts are now editable by going to Help -> Keyboard Shortcuts (or pressing Ctrl + /).

[Found in Evernote forums](https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/131211-feature-released-in-version-108-disable-global-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 0):

Evernote Clipper is the app that is hijacking some of your keyboard combinations at a system level.

To stop the clipper (in Windows):

1. Exit Evernote
2. In Windows Task Manager kill the Evernote Clipper task that is running

   Now to stop clipper running ever again...
3. Run regedit and in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Evernote\Evernote\StartEvernoteClipper` set this to 0

   This will stop Clipper starting up when you start Evernote for windows.
4. Run windows task manager -> Start-up tab -> RMB on Evernote Clipper and set it to disable.

   This is to stop Evernote clipper from starting on windows startup.

This works as of Evernote 6.18.4.8489.

Note: Every time Evernote updates you might want to check that they haven't reset some of these settings and Clipper is not now starting up again.

Answer (score 0):

This ovrerrided everythign and I can't use my PC like a normal keyboard oriented person. And the lack of any means of contact and supprt is horrible!! Never use it, if you use minimum of ctrl+c ctrl+v keyboard shortcuts for your work. If you do, you'd need to re-assign every key set.

Comment: Sorry. This is a product complaint, not an answer. I realize that as a new poster here you can't add comments. You may want to post your own question, with a link to this, and see if you can get help.